# Evaluation of $ \lim_{z \to 0+} \frac{1}{z^4} \int_{0}^{z} cos(x^2)x^3dx $

Tags: calculus, limits

Question :

> > Evaluate 
> >     $$
> > \lim_{z \to 0^+} \frac{1}{z^4} \int_{0}^{z} cos(x^2)x^3dx
> > $$ 
> >     by using
> >     $$
> > \int_{a}^{b} f(x)g(x)dx = f(c)\int_{a}^{b} g(x)dx
> > $$

**My answer is $\frac{1}{4}$.**

[image]

My friend obtained a different answer 1.
Which one is correct?

**Thank you for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct. I give an other proof. Let
$$F(z)=\int_0^z\cos(x^2)x^3dx$$
and by the fundamental theorem of analysis and using the l'Hôpital's rule we have
$$\lim_{z \to 0^+} \frac{1}{z^4} \int_{0}^{z} cos(x^2)x^3dx=\lim_{z \to 0^+} \frac{F(z)}{z^4}=\lim_{z \to 0^+} \frac{\cos(z^2)z^3}{4z^3}=\frac14$$

Comment: you have to use the equation above to prove it.

Comment: Sorry @LAcarguy I don't understand what equation do you mean?

Comment: i mean the equation he is asked to use to get the answer.

Comment: @LAcarguy, no Sami said you are correct and is just giving an alternative proof for future references.

Answer (score 1):

You can also expand the integrand as a Taylor series built around $x=0$ starting with $$\cos(y)=1-\frac{y^2}{2}+\frac{y^4}{24}+O\left(y^6\right)$$ Now, replace $y$ by $x^2$ and multiply the result by $x^3$. So, the integrand is $$cos(x^2)x^3=x^3-\frac{x^7}{2}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ Integrate between $0$ and $z$ to get $$ \int_{0}^{z} cos(x^2)x^3dx \simeq \frac{z^4}{4}-\frac{z^8}{16}$$ I let you finishing.